# This Site, Android Devices, and iOS Devices

Tags: discussion

Is there a version of this site for iOS as well yet?

Comment: This *will* be closed or at least moved (it's meta) according to the rules. BTW, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is where you should go.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent Stack Exchange site for iOS (and Apple products in general) is [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).